# .htaccess redirect non-www to www except one directory not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all non-www to www. Except for the requests pointing inside /cgi-bin/mail-dada/

I can't think of why the code below also redirects http://something.com/cgi-bin/mail-dada/mail.cgi/admin/ to the www-prepended version.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.something\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/mail-dada/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.something.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you have other rules ? Maybe older rule in cache (try it with another browser or clear your cache)

Comment: Yeah actually I just realized it myself, it was stupid browser redirect cache. The rules work. You could add it as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule in your question should be working.

I suspect a cache problem (maybe old rules ?).
Try it with another browser or clear your cache and try again.

Also, if you don't want to hard-code your domain name, you can do it that way (if you have only `www` or `non-www` subdomains)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/mail-dada/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes it was a cache problem, worked in another browser, thank you.